# group a list of triples into map with pair key

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of `triples`

```
List<Triple<String, String, String>> triplets;
```

I want to group into a map like this

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, String> mapping;
```

Where `value` of the map is the third element of the triple. And in case of the same `key` it should override the remaining third value.

For example

```
def triples = [ {a, b, c} ; {a, d, e} ; {a, b, f } ]
// grouping
def map = [ {a,b} : c ; {a, d} : e ]
```

How to do that using `Java 8` and its `grouping` in streams?

Comment: I think the result should be `Map<Pair<String, String>, List<String>> mapping;`. 
Ex: `[ {a,b} : [c, f] ; {a, d} : [e] ]`

Comment: what is the type of Triple

Comment: "And in case of the same key it should override the remaining third value." Then you are not really grouping, are you? Why not just use a classic loop?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `f` overwrite the `c` in the expected output? Or did you mean "ignore the remaining third value"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, String> result = triplets.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            t -> new Pair(t.getOne(), t.getTwo()),
            Triple::getThree,
            (v1, v2) -> v2
        )
    );
```

Example of a partial pair class:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    //...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return one.hashCode() + two.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Pair))
            return false;
        Pair p = (Pair) obj;
        return p.one.equals(one) && p.two.equals(two);
    }
}
```

The `HashMap` class uses `equals` method to identify key objects uniquely. So you first need to override `equals` and `hashcode` methods to show the logical equality of the `Pair` objects for the `Map` class.

Then come back to the streams and lambda. For each triplet use `Collectors.toMap` with the `Pair` object as the key and the other remaining value of the `Triplet` as the value. Then provide a `mergeFunction` to handle key conflicts. In your case, you need to keep the previous value while discarding new value. That's all you need to do.

**Update**

I have updated the merge function as per the below comments.

Comment: Dang, did not think of the `mergeFunction`... this is much cleaner.

Comment: use generics instead of raw types i.e. `t -> new Pair(t.getOne(), t.getTwo())` to --> `t -> new Pair1<>(t.getOne(), t.getTwo())`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Collectors.groupingBy`, you can combine it with downstream `mapping` and `reducing` `Collectors`:

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class Triple {
    String x, y ,z;
}
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class Pair {
    String x, y;
}

List<Triple> lst = List.of(new Triple("a", "b", "c"),
                           new Triple("a", "d", "e"),
                           new Triple("a", "b", "f"));

Map<Pair, String> map = lst.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> new Pair(t.x, t.y),
                 Collectors.mapping(t -> t.z, 
                 Collectors.reducing(null, (x,y) -> y))));
// {Pair(x=a, y=b)=f, Pair(x=a, y=d)=e}
```

You could also change `(x,y) -> y` to `(x,y) -> x` to keep the first occurrance instead.

Answer (score 0):

here ici a possible solution

```
        String[] l1=new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] l2={"a", "d", "e"};

    String[] l3={"a", "b", "c"};
    List<String[]> t=new ArrayList<>();
    t.add(l1);

    t.add(l2);
    t.add(l3);

    Map<String[],String> m=t.stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(x->new String[]{x[0],x[1]}, x->x[2],(x,y)->x));
```

but It depends on the type of **Triple** if it override equals there will be no duplication otherwise it will be duplication in the key of the map

Comment: Arrays do not implement content based `hashCode`/`equals` methods, which makes them rarely useful for map keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Map::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, String> result = new HashMap<>();
triplets.forEach(e -> result.merge(new Pair<>(e.getOne(), e.getThree()), e.getThree(), (o, n) -> o));
```

This inserts the elements of the `triplets` list into a map where the keys are a pair representing the first and second value of the `Triple` and the values of the map are the third value of the `Triple`.

In the case of a key collision, we use the remapping function `(o, n) -> o` to maintain the old (`o`) value.